# Import error :No module named MYSQLdb

Tags: mysql, python3

I have a problem so a connection a python to database local of MySQLdb.

Message of error is:

```
import MYSQL    
ImportError:No module named MYSQLdb.
```

This is a script in python 3.4 to connection my database local MYSQL.

```
import MYSQLdb
conn=MYSQLdb.connect (host ="localhost", user="root" , passwd="abcd",db="nomi")
cursore=conn.cursor()
name=input("Write your name :   ")

x="insert into user (name) values ('%s')"%(name)
cursore.excute(x)
connet.comit()
```

PS: Can you help me please?

Answer (score 11):

You have to install the module with:

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

Reference: [This thread on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459766/installing-mysql-python)

Comment: yes , it is installed.

Comment: Yes , it was installed a  module.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved my issue

Answer (score 11):

`sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev`
then

- for python 2.x:

  `pip install mysql-python`
- for python 3.x:

  `pip install mysqlclient` or `pip3 install mysqlclient`

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @user1721265: It looks like this answer tries to instruct readers how install the (apparently) missing `MYSQL` module for Python.

Comment: It looks like OP is only looking for a solution for Python 3 though.

Comment: it is obvious that after seeing "No module MYSQLdb" user have tried to install it, but if it still showing the Import Error msg try to install 'libmysqlclient-dev' first.

Answer (score 3):

I got this issue solved by the following line

```
pip install pymysql
```

Also updated the MySql configuration line to

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://.............'
```

Comment: This is strange. Before installing this, it didn't work, then I installed it, nothing worked, I uninstalled it, and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately MySQLdb does not support Python 3.

You basically have two options:

1. Run your script using python2.7, that way you won't need to change the MySQL module. The downside is that you'll probably have to convert some code to python2.x.
2. Look for python3.x supported modules as explained here: [Python 3.4.0 with MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23376103/python-3-4-0-with-mysql-database).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, MySQLdb does not support Python 3.  From the page '[MySQL-python]'[1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/) updated on 2013-06-08:

```
* Python versions 2.4-2.7; Python 3 support coming soon.
```

mysqlclient-python (https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python) claims support for python 3 but I have no experience with that product.  Personally, I use pyodbc (also requires libmyodbc) which looks very similar from a programming point of view.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @technodivesh worked for me in debian 9 and python 3.5. But with a little modification.

Instead of

```
sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev
```

I used:

```
sudo apt install default-libmysqlclient-dev
```

It was suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043900/package-libmysqlclient-dev-has-no-installation-candidate)

The first command returned me-

> E: Package 'libmysqlclient-dev' has no installation candidate

[I would have added this as a comment to his answer. But, I do not have the required reputation to make comments.]

Answer (score 0):

For Python3 its

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

Other commands I ran that may or may not be required (the command above ultimately solved everything for me)

```
#this was for a new machine set up. one or two of the below failed
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install mysqlclient
pip3 install mysql-connector
pip3 install mysql-connector-python
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy. You have to write just like this:

```
import Mysql.connector

mydb = Mysql.connector.connect(
  host="127.0.0.1",
    user="root",
  passwd="shriram@11"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE mydatabase")
```

This code will run correctly without showing any module error