# Package 'libmysqlclient-dev' has no installation candidate

Tags: mysql, docker

Facing

```
E: Package 'libmysqlclient-dev' has no installation candidate
```

I am using this blog for reference: 
https://rehalcon.blogspot.com/2018/03/dockerize-your-django-app-for-local.html

Here is my docker file:

```
    FROM python:2-slim
    LABEL org.label-schema.name='app-dj'


    RUN apt-get clean && \
        apt-get update && \
        apt-get install -y \
        curl \
        vim \
        tmux \
        build-essential \
        libjpeg-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        python-dev  \
        libmysqlclient-dev && \
        pip install -U pip 3to2

    COPY requirements.txt req.txt
    RUN  pip install -r /req.txt

    RUN mkdir -p /app
    WORKDIR /app
    EXPOSE 8069
    CMD python /app/server.py
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue on Ubuntu 14.04. What version are you using?

Comment: I was using the docker image python:2-slim, this above docker file is working for Ubuntu:16.04

Comment: It seems different versions point to slightly different repos.  I was able to get it to work with the default-libmysqlclient-dev package instead.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Try to use:

`default-libmysqlclient-dev` in your `Dockerfile`

instead of `libmysqlclient-dev`

Comment: can you explain why this package is not available? Is there any difference between them?

Comment: you can find answer to that ^ here > https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/issues/187#issuecomment-394149643